# Is it OK for a DirectShow filter to seek the filters upstream from itself?

Tags: directshow

Normally seek commands are executed on a filter graph, get called on the renderers in the graph and calls are passed upstream by filters until a filter that can handle the seek does the actual seek operation.

Could an individual filter seek the upstream filters connected to one or more of its input pins in the same way without it affecting the downstream portion of the graph in unexpected ways? I wouldn't expect that there wouldn't be any graph state changes caused by calling IMediaSeeking.SetPositions upstream.

I'm assuming that all upstream filters are connected to the rest of the graph via this filter only.

Obviously the filter would need to be prepared to handle the resulting BeginFlush, EndFlush  and NewSegment calls coming from upstream appropriately and distinguish samples that arrived before and after the seek operation. It would also need to set new sample times on its output samples so that the output samples had consistent sample presentation times. Any other issues?

Comment: This should be possible but unusual. You need to just implement IMediaSeeking yourself on your Output Pins. What do you want to do?

Comment: I think it's possible - eventually the seek operation is about restarting streaming at new position and downstream chain simply expects seamless connection in the streamed samples without caring much whether source was re-seeked. On the other hand, indeed the filter which separates seeked and non-seeked parts need to handle flushing and segment notification, as well as media sample time adjustment.

Comment: Thanks. The intention of seeking is to join sections of the upstream sources without the complexities of multiple graphs and GMF bridge.

Comment: BTW the idea of seeking in order to continue (append) from another position is a scenario which DirectShow developers had in mind at some point. Demultiplexer exposing [`AM_SEEKING_CanDoSegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407038) were supposed to hide EOS notifications and indicate segment completion instead. This enables looping and appending. However, this part remains incomplete and filters (with very rare exceptions) don't have support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly feasible to do what you require. I used this approach to build video and audio mixer filters for a video editor. A full description of the code is available from the BBC White Papers 129 and 138 available from http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd

A rather ancient version of the code can be found on www.SourceForge.net if you search for AAFEditPack. The code is written in Delphi using DSPack to get access to the DirectShow headers. I did this because it makes it easier to handle com object lifetimes - by implementing smart pointers by default. It should be fairly straightforward to transfer the ideas to a C++ implementation if that is what you use.

The filters keep lists of the sub-graphs (a section of a graph but running in the same FilterGraph as the mixers). The filters implement a custom version of TBCPosPassThru which knows about the output pins of the sub-graph for each media clip. It handles passing on the seek commands to get each clip ready for replay when its point in the timeline is reached. The mixers handle the BeginFlush, EndFlush, NewSegment and EndOfStream calls for each sub-graph so they are kept happy.  The editor uses only one FilterGraph that houses both video and audio graphs. Seeking commands are make by the graph on both the video and audio renderers and these commands are passed upstream to the mixers which implement them.

Sub-graphs that are not currently active are blocked by the mixer holding references to the samples they have delivered. This does not cause any problems for the FilterGraph because, as Roman R says, downstream filters only care about getting a consecutive stream of sample and do not know about what happens upstream.

Some key points you need to make sure of to avoid wasted debugging time are:

1. Your decoder filters need to be able to queue to the exact media frame or audio time. Not as easy to do as you might expect, especially with compressed formats such as mpeg2, which was designed for transmission and has no frame index in the files. If you do not do this, the filter may wait indefinitely to get a NewSegment call with the correct media times.
2. Your sub graphs need to present a NewSegment time equal to the value you asked for in your seek command before delivering samples. Some decoders may seek to the nearest key frame, which is a bit unhelpful and some are a bit arbitrary about the timings of their NewSegment and the following samples.
3. The start and stop times of each clip need to be within the duration of the file. Its probably not a good idea to police this in the DirectShow filter because you would probably want to construct a timeline without needing to run the filter first. I did this in the component that manages the FilterGraph.
4. If you want to add sections from the same source file consecutively in the timeline, and have effects that span the transition, you need to have two instances of the sub-graph for that file and if you have more than one transition for the same source file, your list needs to alternate the graphs for successive clips. This is because each sub graph should only play monotonically: calling lots of SetPosition calls would waste cpu cycles and would not work well with compressed files.
5. The filter's output pins define the entire seeking behaviour of the graph. The output sample time stamps (IMediaSample.SetTime) are implemented by the filter so you need to get them correct without any missing time stamps. and you can also set the MediaTime (IMediaSample.SetMediaTime) values if you like, although you have to be careful to get them correct or the graph may drop samples or stall.

Good luck with your development. If you need any more information please contact me through StackOverflow or DTSMedia.co.uk

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I'll dig into that code you referenced.